# Create dynamic type from environment variable in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

There is a type that needs to be created in order to have custom strings inside. Something like:

```
type Names = { customName: "name1" | "name2" }
```

Since, what is planned is to have the "nameX" called from `.env` variables, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
type Names = {customName: process.env.name1 |  process.env.name2 }
```

Instead, as a result, the `process.` is not recognized `Cannot find namespace 'process'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.env` is an Object, not a type!

I think what you're trying to say is

```js
type Names = {
    customName: typeof process.env.name1 | typeof process.env.name2
}
```

However, the type definition of `process.env` is

```js
interface ProcessEnv extends Dict<string> {
    TZ?: string;
}
```

So if you want to achieve your purpose, you need to redefine `process.env` like this

```js
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
            name1?: string
            name2?: string
        }
    }
}
```